# nand2tetris CPU.cmp line 17 problem; outM/(RAM[A]) decrements twice with MD=D-1 instruction;

Tags: nand2tetris

I'm trying to work through the CPU.cmp file, to write out the instructions and see if what's written in CPU.cmp makes sense.

On line 17 (time 8)

```
|time| inM  |  instruction   |reset| outM  |writeM |addre| pc  |DRegiste|
|6+  |     0|0000001111101001|  0  |*******|   0   | 1000|    6|  11111 |a @1001
|7   |     0|0000001111101001|  0  |*******|   0   | 1001|    7|  11111 |a
|7+  |     0|1110001110011000|  0  |  11110|   1   | 1001|    7|  11110 |c MD = D-1; null
|8   |     0|1110001110011000|  0  |  11109|   1   | 1001|    8|  11110 |c
```

As you can see, the value of the D register decrements by 1 from (decimal) 11111 to 11110, and the value of the outM reflects that. However, then outM decrements again, to 11109. Why does it do that? The instruction is MD = D-1, so it should decrement D reg once, and store the value in two locations. How does it happen that RAM[A] and D end up with different values?

I expected them to be the same...

Comment: You, Sir,  put a bug in your CPU so either find it yourself or show your work and ask for help.

Comment: This was in the CPU.cmp file provided with the project, not my CPU.hdl test output... so it does look wrong?

Comment: OK, I misunderstood you, thought your CPU failed at comparison and you're asking why .cmp looks like it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At `tick 7+` CPU has to perform instruction `MD=D-1` as you figured out already.

At this point `D=11111`.

Instruction is `D-1` and the CPU will internally calculate this value,
so `outM`( output bus, not actual memory) is `D-1` (11110) and register D = 11110 as well. At `tock 8` write to memory happens so 11110 is saved at address in register A.
CPU still calculates `D-1` so `outM = 11109`, completely correct behaviour of CPU, we don't use this value but it represents result of last instruction (still D-1).

To expand on `ticks` and `tocks`:

`tick` is the 1 on clock, it's the part of the cycle where all outputs and registers have time to change and stabilize their **internal** values. Registers being loaded output their changing internal state immediately as input changes.

`tock` is the part that clocked parts start emitting their internal state and won't change their internal values.

That's why DRegister has the same value as outM on `tick`, ALU feeds D-1 as their value. Then comes `tock` and D starts emitting its new value(d-1) and ALU calculates its new value (you see it as D-2). D doesn't change because in `tock` phase clocked parts don't change their value.

Also to answer

> How does it happen that RAM[A] and D end up with different values

They don't, outM and DRegister end up with different values. outM is not clocked, it's direct output of ALU, which calculates out(D) - 1. DRegister has the same ALU output as an input but it won't update its value because of clock phase.

Comment: "CPU still calculates D-1 so outM = 11109, completely correct behaviour of CPU"   


I'm not getting something still. If it's completely normal that outM line changes again, then why doesn't Dregister also change at tock 8? Isn't the Dregister fed directly by outM?  

I think I'm not getting something about the ticks and the tocks. Is tick when the fetching of instruction happens, and tock the execution?

Comment: Please, see the updated answer. I still recommend to go through the project. This course takes amazing incremental approach and projects are pretty much self explanatory this way.